# Archive of post format for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-formats

Im using the CPT UI plugin to create my custom post types. I was wondering what i needed to do in order to see an archive of my custom post type by post format ie..

usually for default posts the url is example.com/type/audio

i have tried example.com/resource/type/audio but it does not work.

I have read some places you can do it, and other places can't.  any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no rewrite rules generated for post formats specific to post type. If you want pretty URLs for post type specific post formats, you need to [add them yourself](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

```
// post_type doesn't seem to work,
// add rules to set custom query var
function resource_post_formats_urls() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'resource/type/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&resource_only=1',
        'top'
    );
    // pagination
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'resource/type/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?',
        'index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]&resource_only=1',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'resource_post_formats_urls' );

// add query var so it's recognized
function resource_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'resource_only';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'resource_query_vars' , 10, 1 );

// check if query var is set and modify post_type for the query
function modify_resource_tax_query( $query ) {
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['resource_only'] ) ){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('resource') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_resource_tax_query' );
```

Note that this will only handle incoming requests for existing formats. You'll need to manually create the links to these pages.

Another way to handle it is to create your own custom format taxonomy and set the `rewrite` `slug` to `resource/type`.

Comment: HI, i  changed the rewrite slug to "resource/type" but i still cant get it to work to show the post format.. Am i missing something?

Comment: changed the rewrite slug of what? that would be the slug of a new custom taxonomy used to duplicate the function of post formats.

Comment: i have a custom taxonomy called resource category ('resource-category' is the slug and it is attached to the CPT called 'resource') under CPT UI plugin i changed the 'custom rewrite slug' value to "resources/type" is that not correct to display post fromat for the CPT? - thanks

Comment: that will display posts with terms from `resource-category` assigned, did you create terms and assign them to posts?

Comment: yes did both, i just want to display posts that have a specific post fromat from the CPT - it seems that it only works for the default post type in WP

Comment: just to be clear, when using your own taxonomy, the built in post formats meta box and functions will not be used at all. this is to mimic post formats, but using a custom taxonomy. you have to create and assign terms with the custom taxonomy meta box.

Comment: ahh i got you, i was trying to have the same setup as the default post type format (example.com/type/audio, example.com/type/video) but for a CPT, i guess there is no way to do it

Comment: well, like I said, you can add your own rewrite rules that set `post_type` and `post_format`, which will work with the built in post format taxonomy.

Comment: put in functions.php and flushed permalinks... when i manually go to url, i don't get 404 error, but rather the archive which returns 0 results -- i have tagged the post format accordingly in the editor, am i being dumb and missing something?

Comment: you're right, post type gets reset to post in the query. without bothering to figure out why that happens, I have a quick fix- I added a new var to replace post type and some code to pick that up and reset it. see above.